# Does wampserver only have files in it's set directory?

Tags: wamp

I have wampserver installed in D:/wamp. I need to know if it has some data somewhere else ( like in registry,... ), because I need to have usable web server on Flash disc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes WAMP has a registry entry in the form of a key. If you want a portable server you can try something like [Uniform Server](http://sourceforge.net/projects/miniserver/). I have used this application and it works fine.

Unless someone knows better I don't think you can use WAMP as a portable server.